# How Sum the data of a column in different rows and bind to textbox with Typescript

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, sum, kendo-grid

I have a data grid and I want to show a total sum of a column in different rows in a text box in another place.

```
         OverTimeDetailGridColumns: kendo.ui.GridColumn = [
            { field: "TransactionDetailId", hidden: true },
            { field: "Row", width: "5%", filterable: false },
            {
                field: "TimeDuration",
                width: "20%",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains",
                        delay: 2000
                    }
                }
            },
           }

        OverTimeDetailList: OverTimeDetailViewModel[] = [];
        OverTimeDetailGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: this.OverTimeDetailList,
            serverPaging: false,
            autoSync: false,
            pageSize: 10,
            batch: false,
            serverSorting: false,
            serverFiltering: false,
        });
```

"TimeDuration is a string type and it shows the hour. I want to show the total sum of the "TimeDuration" in my  HTML code in UI:

```
                 <fieldset class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
                   <label >Total Sum</label>
                   <input type="text"
                   value="{{vm.Sum}}"
                   class="form-control"
                   readonly />
                 </fieldset>
```

I've got a variable and declared a method to sum this.TimeDuration but it doesn't work. please help me if you can.

Comment: Are you looking for the total sum time of Array OverTimeDetailList?

Comment: yes, exactly I need it.